# yii datepicker renderpartial ajax - 4th param to true but not working

Tags: php, ajax, yii, datepicker, renderpartial

Wenn i'm loading the view via ajax the datepicker wont work.
I already set every single .js and .css file via setclientscript to false on ajaxRequest.

```
  Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
  and the other files as well....
```

Wenn i check the source code the datepicker input fields are registered

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
 jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('#date_from').datepicker({'showAnim':'fold'});
jQuery('#date_to').datepicker({'showAnim':'fold'});
...
```

I also set the renderPartial 4th param to true

```
  $this->renderPartial('my_view', array(some variables...), false, true);
```

I also gave evry datepicker on the page a unique ID. That helped neither.

When i reload the page everythign works fine, but via ajaxRequest the datepicker doesnt appear... thats pretty strange

SOLUTION EDIT:

i put at the end of my view the following code:

***EDIT: GOT THE SOLUTION:***

i put at the bottom of my view:

```
$("#my_datepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker");
$("#my_datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
$("#my_datepicker").datepicker();
```

Comment: Are you reinitializing datepicker after ajax response?

Comment: how can i do that? at the bottom of the view via     $(document).ready(function() { initialise my datepicker?

Comment: By doing `$('#date_form').datepicker();` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Adding as answer to accept*

After Ajax request reinitialize your datepicker simply by recalling it once more:

```
$("#my_datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
$("#my_datepicker").datepicker();
```